# Select in SQL Server don't work in MySQL, Stuff Function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, for-xml-path

Currently I have a select done in SQL Server and must have the same result for MySQL, achieving a scrip that works in the two would be even better . Below the script:

```
select STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + m_e.NAME + '=' + CAST(v.VALUE AS VARCHAR(MAX)) FROM MMP_USER_METADATA_INSTANCE i
    left outer join MMP_USER_METADATA_INST_VALUE v on (i.id=v.USER_METADATA_INSTANCE_ID)
    left outer join MMP_METADATA_ENTRY m_e on (v.METADATAENTRY_ID=m_e.id)
    WHERE (u.id = i.USER_ID) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')   ,1,2,'') AS 'Campos Adicionais' from mmp_user u

Tables:
MMP_USER_METADATA_INSTANCE,
MMP_USER_METADATA_INST_VALUE,
MMP_METADATA_ENTRY,
MMP_USER.
```

Result:

```
<table border="1"><tr BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF"><th>Campos Adicionais</th></tr>
<tr><td>Skype=Testes, Centro de Custo=16, Endereço Bairro=Teste, Endereço Cidade=, Estado Civil=44, Filhos=38, Graduação Curso=, Graduação Faculdade=Teste, Nivel de Idioma Inglês=46, Nivel de Idioma Espanhol=46, Outro Idioma=Teste, Link Linkedin=, Link Facebook=Teste, Esporte=teste, Time de Futebol=teste</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `stuff` is not a mysql function :P  I think you can use `group_concat` for equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you want something like this:

```
select (SELECT group_concat(m_e.NAME, '=', value separator ',')
        FROM MMP_USER_METADATA_INSTANCE i left outer join
             MMP_USER_METADATA_INST_VALUE v
             on i.id = v.USER_METADATA_INSTANCE_ID left outer join
             MMP_METADATA_ENTRY m_e
             on v.METADATAENTRY_ID = m_e.id
        WHERE u.id = i.USER_ID
       ) `Campos Adicionais`
from mmp_user u;
```